# Making a Procmail regex recipe for malicious email body text

Tags: linux, regular-expression, procmail

At work we recently began receiving emails with what looks like malicious code contained in the email body. I'm trying to create a procmail recipe that will use regex to match only the non-word characters listed in a long string like this one:

`/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#Afe0:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#Jenny:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#preston:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#Afectarac:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#FORTHCO:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#backgrounds:/]\/[%}(-:{{[%+\!(?|}[[+{>-|*;\]}>?]}?(>:-\-/[\[%-=\//>[??+]}}(:)/|{/#legumes`

Note there are no spaces. This is a small example, some emails have lines over 20,000 characters long. This is messing with our spam filtering and I'm hoping there's a way to match long lines of non-word characters with no whitespace separators. So far I've tried using several variants/pieces/combinations of what is below with only partial success - I'm having trouble finding a way to make this work without also catching a lot of false-positives:

```
:0 
* B ?? ^.*(!@#$%^&*()[]{})+ && ! </([a-z|A-Z])/>
$DEFAULT/MalSpam/
```

I was thinking that if I can make a regex that matches, then I can combine that with another rule that sends the email to a separate directory if the total characters per line exceed a certain amount, say 500. Haven't got that part figured out yet...other regex I've used in the past had the \W flag that matched only non-word characters, does procmail have an equivalent? How can I do this?

Comment: Do you run your own email server, or are you filtering as a client only? ... The solution you are working on may filter out all non-text attachments and/or inline images.  Is there any need for viewing company email in html mode, or is plain text just fine?  Are the company email clients viewing their email via a web browser or a separate client like MS Outlook or Claws or Thunderbird?

Comment: We administer the servers, however they are shared machines so the procmail filtering is set up per-account in most cases. In other words I personally can't use anything other than the /home/user/.procmailrc file or make system-wide changes to procmail.

Comment: Whoops, hit Enter too soon. The emails in question will only show the long lines in plain-text mode, the html mode just shows a link to a malicious web page as its payload. These malicious emails have text that's unique enough that I think I can send them to the bitbucket if I can get a working recipe, so the clients ideally would never see these emails at all. I don't have any knowledge of what email client the end-user has, for the moment I'm just using the webmail interface since that seems to be the most common tool for our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question about `\W`, you don't need it. You can just do the inverse of `\w`. For example, if you consider this to be word characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (that's Vim's definition of `\w`, for example) then use `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

The superficial fix of your attempt would be

```
:0 
*   B ?? [][!@#$%^&*(){}]+
* ! B ?? </[a-zA-Z]+/>
$DEFAULT/MalSpam/
```

if I am guessing correctly that you are trying to match a sequence of two or more of the punctuation characters, and a sequence of characters which are alphabetics between `</` and `/>` as a negated condition (meaning a match if present prevents the recipe from matching).

*However,* any two punctuation characters (like just `!!`) will match the first regex; and I don't see why you articulate the second condition like you did.

A challenge is that many punctuation characters are regex metacharacters.  To match a literal `[` or `(` or `*` you need to backslash-escape them, or put them in a character class. (A character class containing `[` is `[[]` which takes a while to wrap your head around. That's a literal `[` inside the character class brackets `[`...`]`. And a character class containing `]` and `[` needs to have them in this order, so `[][]`.)  I made the first regex simple by putting *everything* in a character class, but as it is, it is probably too broad. I would perhaps require there to be a sequence of, say, four or five in sequence. (Unfortunately, Procmail's regex variant doesn't support `egrep`'s `[class]{5,}` numeric quantifier; it would be handy here.)

```
:0B
* [][!@#$%^&*(){}][][!@#$%^&*(){}][][!@#$%^&*(){}][][!@#$%^&*(){}][][!@#$%^&*(){}]
* ! </[a-zA-Z]+/>
$DEFAULT/MalSpam/
```

If you look carefully, you see that the first one is `[][!@#$%^&*(){}]` repeated five times.  If you want to make it longer (like, 500 adjacent occurrences) just repeat as many times as necessary.  If the entire expression is longer than `LINEBUF`, you'll need to watch out for that as well -- if you want to make room for a seven-character regex 500 times, that's 10,200 bytes, so you need to make sure `LINEBUF` is at least that big before the recipe which contains this long expression.

Notice also how a `B` flag on the recipe removes the requirement to put `B ??` on each individual recipe line.

If you want to compare the message's length, simply use `>` and the number you want.  With the `:0B` flag, `* > 512` will match a *body* which is longer than 512 bytes.

For your final question, `\W` is basically equivalent to the character class `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` (a single character which is not in the range `A-Z` or the range `a-z` or the range `0-9` or the character `_`).

Comment: I already answered OP's final question.

Comment: @BLayer I saw your partial answer but I like for this to be self-contained ... and anyway, I wrote it before I reloaded the page to see your answer.